# print statements

Tags: macos, programming

Is it possible for a bad guy to read print statements done in the swift programming language?

Ex. If I release an app to the Apple Appstore and it has following print line: 
`print("my-secret-password")` is it then possible to read this print somewhere in the operating system or listen for these prints using a certain application?

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is this:

If you have any hardcoded password in any piece of client side code, then it should be considered discoverable. This goes for any application on any platform.

It's not just print statements, but any code whatsoever. Even obfuscated code can be decompiled and analysed.

We have various questions on here related to this problem. Have a look at [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/162087/485) and the Related sidebar on that page.

Comment: But password or not can I as a 'bad guy' some how see these print messages ?

Comment: Of course - it doesn't matter whether it is in a print statement or not. **Anything** in code client side can be read by a bad guy